# jQuery delete and fade

Tags: ajax, jquery

Im using jQuery to delete and fade the item container. This code will delete and fade div class box2. what i want to do this to fade div class box1. without changing the delete link to box1.

if anyone can point me out how to do this, highly appropriated. thanks in advace.

```
<div class="box1">

<div class="box2">

<a href="#" id="1" class="delete">x</a>

</div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#load').hide();
});

$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $('#load').fadeIn();
        var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var string = 'id=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delete.php",
            data: string,
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
                $('#load').fadeOut();
            }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your #load element?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with : . without changing the delete link to box1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(function() {
    $('#load').hide();

    $('.delete').click(function(){
        $('#load').fadeIn();

        $(this).parent().slideUp('slow', function () {
            $('.delete').appendTo('.box1')
            $(this).remove();
            $('#load').fadeOut();
        });

        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to `var commentContainer = $(this).parent().parent();`. It will now target .box1. You can then unwrap .box2 :

```
commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {
    $('.box2').unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
var commentContainer = $(this).parent().parent();
```

to get to .box1 and not .box2 Does that solve the problem?

Just a couple of comments though. A valid id should start with an alphabetic character. The digit '1' is not valid. 'a1' would be better, or just 'a'. Also use the ajax callback `done` rather than `success` as it is currently deprecated.